# Aiming a gun (At, on, in)

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality

I wonder because I've seen fiction that says "He aimed his rifle at the enemy" and other times "He aimed his rifle on the enemy" and at times "He aimed his gun in the enemy" and I wonder what is the correct way to say that a gun is being aimed? Is it at? In? On?

Comment: Not "in".  And "on" would only be used in certain contexts.

Comment: So what would be the correct usage? "At"?

Comment: I would use 'at'. I would only use 'on' with 'trained' rather than 'aimed' (and I wouldn't use 'at' with 'trained' either.

Comment: @Hot Licks Could you please provide an example of such a conetxt where ‘aim the rifle on’ would be used?